# agora video call flutter how to make multiple people open live video and people can choose with one to join

Tags: flutter, dart, agora

I'm using flutter to test and the app im testing on is a chat app with video call function and many users can open their own live to other to join all with the same channel name and token. can I distinguish everyone that have their live opened so i can direct people who wants to join specific live video stream

I tried by using different uid but didn't work